# How to instantiate a java class in Jython with type casting

Tags: java, casting, jython

Due to technical issues created by the vendor, old version of Jython 2.7.0, etc.. I am stuck trying to do REST-ful calls that use JSON in Jython using Java classes. The Jython version is too old for the `requests` module.  I found [this](https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post) example.  Removed the "new" in section "2.1. Create a URL Object".  Now progress is blocked trying to type cast a Java Class in Jython.

```
con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()
```

Does anyone know how to do a type casting of a Java Class in Jython?
Or is there another way to get around this issue?

Comment: Doesn't Jython do this automatically? What happens if you just do `con = url.openConnection()`?

Comment: I'm suprised the first line of code didn't catch you:
    URL url = new URL ("https://reqres.in/api/users");
It should be:
    url = URL ("https://reqres.in/api/users");
Basically, remove the "new"s, remove the typecasting, remove mention of types in general, and remove the semicolons and braces and you have jython.

Comment: I removed the "new" in section "2.1. Create a URL Object" and did not put that in the original post.  The OP has been fixed.

Comment: I just used the SSL Object HttpsURLConnection instead of the interface HttpURLConnection.